# SQL Server 2012: Create audit failed (user permission)

Tags: sql-server-2012

I am logged in SQL Server 2012 as db_owner user, I am trying to create an Audit but I receive this error:

> User does not have permission to perform this action

What kind of permission does the user need? And how I can assign the new permission to the user?

**EDIT**

Tried that :

```
USE master;
GO
GRANT ALTER ANY SERVER AUDIT TO AuditConfigurationLogin
```

But I cant change permissions to myself:

> Cannot grant, deny, or revoke permissions to sa, dbo, entity owner,
>   information_schema, sys, or yourself.

Comment: Permission "ALTER ANY SERVER AUDIT"?

Comment: @duDE tried but I cant update the permissions of myself

Comment: Have you tried REVOKE ALTER ANY SERVER AUDIT ?

Comment: @dude can you provide the full command?